# ROR Tutorial book: Why does a link with href="#" pass a click_link test that checks content on another page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

At the end of Chapter 5 there are some exercises that add these tests:

```
    click_link 'Contact'
    expect(page).to have_title(full_title('Contact'))


    click_link 'Home'
    click_link 'Sign up now!'
    expect(page).to have_title(full_title('Sign Up'))

    click_link 'sample app'
    expect(page).to have_title(full_title(''))
  end
```

full_title() is defined like this:

```
  def full_title(page_title) 
    base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"

    if page_title.empty?
      base_title
    else
      "#{base_title} | #{page_title}"
    end
  end
```

The "Sign up now!" button/link takes me to a page with this source html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Sign Up</title>
    ...
</head>

<body>
    <header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">

    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container">
        <a href="#" id="logo">sample app</a>

    ...

</html>
```

So how can clicking the "sample app" link, with href="#", go to a page where the title is just:

> Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App

i.e. the Home page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh...have_title() does partial matches, i.e. have_title() checks to see if the title on the page *contains* the specified text.  Because the title on the Sign Up page is:

> Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Sign Up

...that contains full_title(''), which is `Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App`, and therefore the test:

```
click_link 'sample app'
expect(page).to have_title(full_title(''))
```

passes.  That is a BUG in the tests.  An additional test should be added:

```
click_link 'sample app'
expect(page).to have_title(full_title(''))
expect(page).not_to have_title("|")  #<--HERE
```

which will then fail.  To get the additional test to pass, you need to change the `_header.html.erb` partial from this:

```
  <header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container">
        <%= link_to "sample app", "#", id: "logo" %>  #<--CHANGE THE LINK HERE
```

to this:

```
  <header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container">
        <%= link_to "sample app", root_path, id: "logo" %>
```

After changing that, if you click the `SAMPLE APP` logo on any page, your browser will take you to the Home page.